# A cyclical or hierarchical dictionary-like data structure in Python (or in CS in general)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-structures

I am currently at a loss since I have a huge Pandas DataFrame (more than 1 million rows) and I am looking at 3 columns - namely the following:

```
Company_Name     Business_ID    Location
ABC, Inc.         BY2389AS        MTV
ABC, Inc.          100020         LMD
XYZW               010012         MTV
XYZW               010012         LMD
XYZW              AB23JKF         QAT
                  BA23F3              
SomethingCo        2342
SomethingCo                       ALD
```

As can be seen, sometimes some of the fields are missing. I want to check this against a given registry (this contains millions of triplets in a CSV format of (Company_Name, Business_ID, Location), and if there is a unique match, try to return the missing fields (if there exists a unique match).

The registry would look something like this in CSV form:

```
Company_Name, Business_ID, Location
ABC, Inc., BY2389AS, MTV
ABC, Inc., 100020, LMD
XYZW, 010012, MTV
XYZW, 010012, LMD
XYZW, AB23JKF, QAT
DLCComp, BA23F3, PLT
DLCComp, 234XYZ, QAT            
SomethingCo, 2342, COD
SomethingCo, 2020 , ALD
```

As can be seen above, nothing is missing from this CSV file.

The caveat is, doing a DataFrame groupby, pivot table, stack/unstack, or even logical lookups and selecting a subset of the dataframe slows this down (since looking through the whole registry takes a long time. I have a set of logic to go through and if certain fields are missing, looking at the registry to handle unique matches and fill in the missing fields; otherwise, just return as-is if a unique match cannot be identified.

A dictionary lookup seems ideal - but since any combination of the 3 fields can be missing, I cannot create dictionary from this giant registry dataframe (which I read into memory for current purposes) and create a key by one of the columns.

I am trying to think of what dataframe would be ideal to handle this, and thought of cyclical or hierarchical dictionaries (if those exist), but that also gets a bit complicated since the lookup would have to adjust to different key-value pairs depending on what value is missing in the database vs. the registry. The cost of re-arranging or subsetting the dataframe based on what column values are available takes a while - and I am trying to find out if there is a good data structure or algorithm that can solve this. I am also trying to see if Pandas might have a very efficient way of subsetting the dataframe by logical operations (which is what I am currently doing) as such:

```
# Example for if Business_ID is populated, but both Company_Name and Location are not:
def specific_case_func_for_demo_purposes(company_name, business_id, location):
    if not company_name and business_id and not location:
        subset_df = registry_df[registry_df[Business_ID] == business_id_im_looking_for]

        if len(subset_df) == 0:
            return company_name, business_id, location
        elif len(subset_df) == 1:
            return subset_df['Company_Name'], business_id, subset_df['Location']
        else:
            # handle case when there are multiple business_id matches by seeing if company name is unique, since company name can be identified by business ID:
            if len(subset_df['Company_Name'].unique()) == 1:
                return subset_df['Company_Name'].iloc[0], business_id, location
            else:
                # can't possible know if there is a unique match - so just return the empty company_name and location
                return company_name, business_id, location
```

This is just a function to handle this particular, specific case when Business_ID is populated but Company_Name and Location is not. This can get convoluted, as can be seen. I am currently handling all 8 cases (some of which can be decreased into duplicates or essentially the same case, so all in all, about 4 cases with a couple subcases), but this seems highly inefficient in both design as well as performance. When using a subset of the registry CSV data of number of rows = 800,000 and performing this type of logic on about ~400 datapoints, this took 35 s with stdev of 128 ms using %timeit. I used a df.apply using the principal function that I devised to time this.

I would like to know a data structure that may provide good lookup and set up time when applying this to much bigger dataframes - I know there has to be a much more efficient way, whether it is using Pandas methods efficiently or different data structures such as mutual-lookup dictionaries (or cyclical or hierarchical dictionaries, if these concepts exist), tree-based methods potentially, or other things. I welcome any input on this.

Comment: will there be any possibilities where you need to find 2 column values when given 1 of the column the value is Location?
My assumption here is 1 unique Company_Name has 'n' Business_ID and for that 1 unique Business_ID (w.r.t company name) has 'n' location

Comment: Sometimes that may be needed, but it's based on the Company_Name & Location. However, it need not necessarily be unique, although the majority cases are (and that is a valid assumption)

Comment: Does this helps ?

Answer (score 0):

> Solution 1 - To optimise dataframe search

```
import sys
import time
import timeit
import random
import pandas as pd
```

```
# Creating dummy data for 1 million rows
number_of_rows = 1000000 # 1 million
list_Temp = [('abcdefghi_'+str(i), 'jklmnopqrs_'+str(i), 'tuvwxyz_'+str(i)) for i in range(number_of_rows)]

# This is your registry_df
df = pd.DataFrame(list_Temp, columns = ['A' , 'B', 'C']) 
print('Dummy registry_df size =', (sys.getsizeof(df)/1000000), 'MB')
df.head()
```

Output:

```
Dummy registry_df size = 217.666774 MB

        A               B             C
0   abcdefghi_0   jklmnopqrs_0    tuvwxyz_0
1   abcdefghi_1   jklmnopqrs_1    tuvwxyz_1
2   abcdefghi_2   jklmnopqrs_2    tuvwxyz_2
3   abcdefghi_3   jklmnopqrs_3    tuvwxyz_3
4   abcdefghi_4   jklmnopqrs_4    tuvwxyz_4
```

>

```
# Creating 'n' random numbers for searching in registry_df
n = 100
list_random_numbers = [random.randrange(0, number_of_rows) for i in range(n)]
```

```
# Time taken for searching for n values in registry_df. You need to select one of the best from option

%timeit for number in list_random_numbers: df_Temp = df.loc[df['A'] == 'abcdefghi_'+str(number)]
%timeit for number in list_random_numbers: df_Temp = df[df['A'] == 'abcdefghi_'+str(number)]
%timeit for number in list_random_numbers: df_Temp = df[df.A.eq("'abcdefghi_"+str(number)+"'")]
%timeit for number in list_random_numbers: df_Temp = df.query(('A == ' + ("'abcdefghi_"+str(number)+"'")))
%timeit for number in list_random_numbers: df_Temp = df.eval("A == 'abcdefghi_"+str(number)+"'")
%timeit for number in list_random_numbers: df_Temp = df[df.A.isin( ["A == 'abcdefghi_"+str(number)+"'"])]
```

Output :

```
11.9 s ± 338 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
11.4 s ± 441 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
13 s ± 756 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
5.57 s ± 384 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
5.22 s ± 122 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
3.99 s ± 140 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

> Solution 2 - If you have a little bit of extra memory. Store indexes in respective column dictionary

```
# Searching dataframe using indexes
# For demo Creating list of 'n' random numbers for searching in registry_df based on indexes

n = 100
list_random_numbers= [random.randrange(0, number_of_rows) for i in range(n)]

# Fetching rows based on index

%timeit for number in list_random_numbers: row = df[df.index.isin([number])]
%timeit for number in list_random_numbers: row = df.iloc[[number]]
```

Ouput:

```
948 ms ± 64.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
27.7 ms ± 2.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

>
Creating a Dictionary which holds indexes

```
dict_Company_Name ={}
dict_Business_ID = {}
dict_Location = {}

def Create_Dictionary_From_DataFrame(df, dict_Company_Name, dict_Business_ID, dict_Location):
    for row_Index in range(len(df)):
        comany_name, business_id, location = df.iloc[row_Index]
        dict_Company_Name.setdefault(comany_name, []).append(row_Index)
        dict_Business_ID.setdefault(business_id, []).append(row_Index)
        dict_Location.setdefault(location, []).append(row_Index)

%time Create_Dictionary_From_DataFrame(df, dict_Company_Name, dict_Business_ID, dict_Location)

Wall time: 2min 12s
```

```
# Size in MB. For you this will vary as I have created dummy data
print((sys.getsizeof(dict_Company_Name))/1000000)
print((sys.getsizeof(dict_Business_ID))/1000000)
print((sys.getsizeof(dict_Company_Name))/1000000)

41.943144
41.943144
41.943144
```

```
# Searching based on indexes

n = 10000 # 1
list_random_numbers = [random.randrange(0, number_of_rows) for i in range(n)]

def specific_case_func_business_id():

    for row_Index in list_random_numbers:
        business_id = 'jklmnopqrs_' + str(row_Index)

        if business_id in dict_Business_ID:
            list_Indexes_Business_ID = dict_Business_ID[business_id]

            if len(list_Indexes_Business_ID) > 0:
                subset_df = df.iloc[list_Indexes_Business_ID]           
                """
                Your case specific code
                """
            else:
                raise Exception('No matching data found for Business ID = ' + business_id )

%timeit specific_case_func_business_id()
```

Output:

```
2.99 s ± 278 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

As seen in searching in dataframe the most optimised method took **~4 secs to search for just 100 values**.
Whereas searching using indexes took **~3 secs for all 10000 values**

Also if you have 2 values and 1 missing value to find. You need to find indexes from the respective dictionary and use below function to get common indexes and finally get subset_df from list of common indexes

```
def Get_Common_List_Values(list1, list2):
    if (list1 is None) and (list2 is not None): return list2
    if (list2 is None) and (list1 is not None): return list1

    if (list2 is not None) and (list1 is not None):
        return [row_Index for row_Index in list1 if row_Index in list2]
```

**Note:** All time are calculated on dummy data. Your actual time will vary